# From python console app to django as UI best practice

Tags: python, django

I have an existing python application that runs in a console. This application contain features that is currently using sqlite3 as its data storage.

I am now trying to make use of Django as the presentation and it seems that I would need some help from you guys on how to speed up my transition from console to a web enabled user interface.

I understand that web is stateless and the app will be mostly consumed several people.

Most of my data is in dict which I can be able to convert to a JSON. I am seeking for kind advice on what are the things that I need to understand or if any of you guys have encountered this kind of app that you will need to migrate to a web centric presentation.

It has mostly query based functions which have few argumenta/parameters passed but it seems that I will have problem with the database access in python due to that most of my db queries are raw sql.

Thank you guys in advance.

(if there is any existing projects that I can use as a pattern by all means please do help to share with me)

==========

## Resolution

Added this into manage.py:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app', 'engine'))
```

Now I can call my 'engine' package classes/scripts.

Comment: sqlite will have major issues if there are concurrent writes ... as such it is not a good candidate for a web storage method ...

Comment: Thanks for the comment Joran. I do understand the sqlite limitation. I can later on migrate it to another data storage. As long as it supports raw sql. What I do not have are models for django. But I do know that I can somehow make use of my existing functions and convert it to models in some ways. What I would like to know if it is possible to have a minimal change in my console app and make it django app. I actually decided earlier this project is to complete the functionality/features and then think about the web ui later on (which is now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty open-ended question, but I'll address moving your database to Django's models and custom queries.

---

#### Data Layer

Before building your app, you can try and use the manage.py command [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) to describe your current schema as Django models. It won't write your model layer for you, but can help you get started.

As @joran-beasley mentioned, sqlite will not be suitable as a production database for a multi-client application. Postgres is widely-used in the Django community, but it is hardly your option that supports raw SQL.

It is possible to migrate some data in XML, YAML, or JSON and import them with django's de/serializers or via the `loaddata` manage.py command. Consider adding custom managers to your models that are the targets of 1-to-1, Foreign Key, or Many-to-Many fields. You can add a custom get_by_natural_key method that can simplify de/serializing data that contains foreign keys, etc.

---

#### Queries

Django's [QuerySet api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/) is a wonderful wrapper for wrap SQL, but it will have some limitations. Take some time to review it's [capabilities and shortcomings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#making-queries) to decide if it can help or hinder your needs.

If you want to continue making raw queries, Django can [help you](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/sql/) with that too as it offers helper queryset methods like `raw` or `extra`. You can avoid the model layer entirely using its `django.db.connection.cursor` class.

---

I can't speak to much else that will help you in your transition, but you may find that Django's class-based generic views like `DetailView`, `ListView`, `UpdateView`, or `DeleteView` may be helpful in setting up some of your more basic interfaces on the web.

Comment: Hi Mr Dave, thank you for all the shared information and it does open up a lot of ideas. It seems like I will need to touch my console app but that also made me think if it is possible to make my console as a 'core' module of this app. What I am thinking right now is that I will make a staging data layer that only the Django will use. And then I will have another set of modules to sync it to the 'core' database (queued or in real-time). In this way, the design will not touch the console app. Is this also a good alternative approach? What do you think are the side effects of this design?

Comment: Just for an update. I have already prepared the UI using Django template(bare html/css) without using generic views and forms. It do seems like everything is in place but the integration of the core modules. Regarding my comment above, I actually think I do not need to have a staging data layer as I should be able to call the core functions directly (please hit me if I am wrong). But I just have doubts of implementing it this way. I might need some guidelines or show me a good path with my problem. My goal is no to minimum change in core so it can still be used via console and via web.

Comment: Django is certainly useful even if you aren't using it's data models and database ORM. I think your revised approach sounds fine, you can always experiment with the staging layer or migrate to Models later on.